# C# Update label from static method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can i update a label from a static method?

I have a Textblock control

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="lblFreeSize" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Free size:"/>
```

which i would like to update it from a static method like so

```
lblFreeSize.Text = "Free size: " + Helper.SizeSuffix(App.free_space.arguments.sizebytes);
```

and here is the helper class :-)

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string SizeSuffix(Int64 value)
    {
       return "something";
    }
}
```

And of course the error returned is an `Invalid cross-thread access.`
And here is the Stack Trace

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
at System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.set_Text(String value)
at Tr.MainPage.GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
```

Comment: At first blush, that looks reasonable to me. What happens when you try?

Comment: First, answer this question: how do you expect your `static` method to know what instance of your window you are dealing with? Why is this method `static` in the first place? More context is needed here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where is the `lblFreeSize.Text =` in? It doesn't seem to be in the static method.

Comment: A static method doesn't have a reference to the window where the control is, unless you send it along in the call. Why is the static method updating the UI? Does the method have to be static? Is the static method that you are talking about the `Helper` method? In that case it looks like you are not at all updating the control from the method, but just using the result from the method to update the control, and that should not pose any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    lblFreeSize.Text = string.Format(
        "Free size: {0}", Helper.SizeSuffix(App.free_space.arguments.sizebytes)))));
```

This will execute the action delegate asynchronously in associated UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use global variable.

App.xaml.cs

```
public new static App Current
{
    get
    {
        return (App)Application.Current;
    }
}

static public myTextBlock = null;
```

At the page where your TextBlock lives:

```
OnNavigateTo(...)
{
   App.myTextBlock = lblFreeSize;
}

OnNavigatedFrom(...)
{
   App.myTextBlock = null;
}
```

and instead of `lblFreeSize.Text` use:

```
if ( App.myTextBlock != null )
{
    App.myTextBlock = "text";
}
```